# AngularJS same html site for insert and update

Tags: html, angularjs, json

This one is going to be a long one :)

So here is the idea,  I wanna use same html page for two controllers , problem is , that page in insert state wont load , because of ng-repeat="employee in employee" because its non existent in insert controller.

What my repeater does it just fills textboxes , it doesnt repeat anything , its just a single form and it fills information of that one single employee , am i doing this wrong ?

employeeUpdate works like a charm , problem is in employeeInsert , is there a posibility that it can fill textboxes without ng-repeat part , because it does not work without it , but it does fill comboBox/select options without it.

```
.state('employeeUpdate', {

          url: '/employeeUpdate?employeeCode=:param1',
          templateUrl: 'pages/employeeUpdate.html',
          controller: 'employeeUpdateCtrl',
          resolve: {
              employeeGatherAll: ['$http', function ($http) {

                  return $http.jsonp("webserviceSite&procedureName=wsEmployeeGatherAll 'param','param'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
                        .success(function (response) {
                            return (response)
                        }).error(function (response) {
                            console.log("failed");
                        });
              }],

            employeeSelectByCode: ['$http','$location', function ($http, $location) {
                var employeeCode = $location.search().employeeCode

                return $http.jsonp("webServiceSite&procedureName=wsEmployeeSelectByCode 'paramet','parame','" + employeeCode + "'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
                      .success(function (response) {

                          return (response)
                      }).error(function (response) {
                          console.log("failed");
                      });
              }]
          }
      })


            .state('employeeInsert', {

                url: '/employeeInsert',
                templateUrl: 'pages/employeeUpdate.html',
                controller: 'employeeInsertCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    employeeGatherAll: ['$http', function ($http) {

                        return $http.jsonp("webServiceSiteUrl&procedureName=wsEmployeeGatherAll 'parametar','parametar'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
                              .success(function (response) {
                                  return (response)
                              }).error(function (response) {
                                  console.log("failed");
                              });
                    }],


                }
            })
```

So i have selectView as well , where i list all employees, and on click i go to employeeUpdate where i send code trough url as well , my html employeeUpdate page looks something like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in employee">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Employee code</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtEmployeeCode" ng-model='employee.employeeCode' />
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
         <label>Status</label>
      <select id="Select3" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.statusCode" ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in employeeGather.status">    
        <option value="">Select status</option>
    </select>
         </div>

</div>
```

And these are the controllers

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('employeeUpdateCtrl', ['$scope', 'employeeGatherAll', 'employeeSelectByCode', function ($scope, employeeGatherAll, employeeSelectByCode) {
        $scope.employee = employeeSelectByCode.data.employee;
        $scope.employeeGather = employeeGatherAll.data
    }])
        .controller('employeeInsertCtrl', ['$scope', 'employeeGatherAll', function ($scope, employeeGatherAll) {
         $scope.employeeGather = employeeGatherAll.data
     }])
```

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make sense.  why would you want to use a page with a repeater on it for displaying only a single element? If you want both pages to share a single template, but one of them to repeat the template, then you should make the template into a directive.

Comment: I forgot to mention i am new to angularJS , i am jquery user :D , and that is only html example , i have more than 25 elements on it , i just put 2 for example ,not going to copy whole html file ,i put  textbox and select so you can see that i am filling both of those in update , and filling only selects in insert , and i am filling it from gather .

I am asking , is it possible to use a single page for it , because my problem is that ng-repeater , is it possible to use same ctrl maybe ? 

And exmplain that part template into directive :) , cheers

Comment: if your `employee` is not an array, then yes, using `ng-repeat` here is incorrect.  It seems like what you want is insert and update to both only operate on one `employee`, and share the template.  without `ng-repeat`, this would be completely reasonable.

Comment: My employee is json, i get it from database , its employeeSelectByCode in main js ,and i have $scope.employee = employeeSelectByCode.data.employee , its json format , which returns all data of ONE employee ,(code , firstName, lastName and so on...)

And my insert and update do insert of one employee , or update of it , 
Would it be logical that filling textboxes would work without that ng-repeat , because in my case it doesnt work without it .It does fill combobox from employeeGather json even tough i removed ng-repeater , but it doesnt fill text-boxes , cheers

Comment: it's not easy to answer that for sure, but it *sounds* like what is happening is that your server is returning an array with only one element in it.  If that is the case, then you should probably use `employee.SelectByCode.data.employee[0]`, but that is just a guess.  definitely using `ng-repeat` is out of place with only one item, though.

Comment: Yep that was it , and it works without ng-repeat, go answer question so i can mark it as answer ,thank you for your time , cheers m8 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

employee.SelectByCode.data.employee[0] was the soulution , without ng-repeat